# How to aggregate qualitative data?

Tags: data, data-mining

I am trying to look for methods to aggregate and find the average of qualitative data.

There are 20 qualitative measures, each divided unevenly into 4 cycles labeled 1-4. I am trying to find which bucket would be the mean? I cannot simply take the average, as that would cause problems if most were labeled 1 and 4. The average could not be 2.5.

I will say that 1 is closely related to the numbers it's next to, 4 and 2(because its a cycle). So, in my previous example, the answer of 2.5 is further incorrect because its saying the mean cycle is one that's most opposite of where most qualitative data is.